# Is it possible to add an Angular 6 App to Umbraco Project

Tags: angular, umbraco

I have an Umbraco Project and it's basically an informative website. Recently, there was a decision to add to it some e-services  (interactive HTML forms) which need Angular 6 or Ajax.

I used Ajax in a similar project to handle the data coming from the server and control the HTML forms, but I found it kind of hard to control it with jQuery and Ajax.

So I want to use Angular inside a CMS project which is Umbraco.

Is it possible? If yes, how can that be done? I've searched a lot but didn't find any result.

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco is a so called "un-opinionated" CMS in that doesn't really interfere with how you build the front-end. Simply put, Umbraco just delivers the data from it's belly and you decide what goes where in your website design.

So yes, you can do pretty much whatever you want or need to do, but there's no "singular" answer as to how you do it.

Comment: however, you may also need to modify the configuration of Umbraco a little to get it to work - namely around reserved urls etc.